# How do I create a df in r composed of grouped or nested counts?

Tags: r

Edited to add: Sample data is now present--thanks to @LMc

Hi, folks. I've got a dataframe like this, filtered from IMDb:

> structure(list(tconst = c("tt0003419", "tt0003419", "tt0004013",
> "tt0005231", "tt0005231", "tt0005615", "tt0005615", "tt0005772",
> "tt0005951", "tt0005951", "tt0006434", "tt0006434", "tt0006554",
> "tt0006820", "tt0007111", "tt0008826", "tt0010323", "tt0010323",
> "tt0010323", "tt0010323"), primaryTitle = c("The Student of Prague",
> "The Student of Prague", "The Ghost Breaker", "The Hound of the Baskervilles",
> "The Hound of the Baskervilles", "Life Without Soul", "Life Without Soul",
> "Mortmain", "Satan's Rhapsody", "Satan's Rhapsody", "Black Orchids",
> "Black Orchids", "The Crimson Stain Mystery", "Homunculus, 1. Teil",
> "A Night of Horror", "Alraune", "The Cabinet of Dr. Caligari",
> "The Cabinet of Dr. Caligari", "The Cabinet of Dr. Caligari",
> "The Cabinet of Dr. Caligari"), startYear = structure(c(-20819,
> -20819, -20454, -20089, -20089, -20089, -20089, -20089, -19358,
> -19358, -19358, -19358, -19724, -19724, -19358, -18628, -18263,
> -18263, -18263, -18263), class = "Date"), runtimeMinutes = c("85",
> "85", "60", "50", "50", "70", "70", "\N", "55", "55", "50",
> "50", "\N", "69", "56", "80", "76", "76", "76", "76"), decade = c(1910,
> 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910,
> 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1920, 1920, 1920, 1920), genre = c("Drama",
> "Fantasy", "Adventure", "Mystery", "Crime", "Drama", "Sci-Fi",
> "Drama", "Fantasy", "Drama", "Drama", "Drama", "Mystery", "Sci-Fi",
> "Drama", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller", "Mystery", "Mystery", "Thriller"
> ), rating = c(6.5, 6.5, 5.2, 3.1, 3.1, 6.6, 6.6, 5.8, 6.8, 6.8,
> 4.8, 4.8, 6.9, 6.1, 6.1, 5.5, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1), numVotes = c(2063,
> 2063, 36, 40, 40, 53, 53, 23, 719, 719, 18, 18, 18, 91, 20, 51,
> 62119, 62119, 62119, 62119)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df",
> "tbl", "data.frame"))

What I want to get is a dataframe of counts sorted by decade and genre, something like this:

| decade | genre | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1910 | Drama | 15 |
| 1920 | Drama | 27 |
| 1930 | Drama | 32 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1910 | Fantasy | 12 |
| 1920 | Fantasy | 23 |
| 1930 | Drama | 41 |
| ... | ... | ... |

...and so on, through each group. I've tried several things, including this:

```
subgenres %>%
 group_by(decade,genre) %>%
 summarise(count=n())
```

But I get this error:

> subgenres %>%
> group_by(decade) %>%
> summarise(count=n())
> Error: 'format_error' is not an exported object from 'namespace:cli'
> Error in count(., decade, genre) : object 'decade' not found

I can count each each subgenres$genre, but I don't know how to nest groups and I'm not sure what my keyword search should be to do the research myself. I thought it was a type problem, but changes there didn't seem to work, either.

```
tibble [6,809 × 8] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
$ tconst        : chr [1:6809] "tt0003419" "tt0003419" "tt0004013" "tt0005231" ...
$ primaryTitle  : chr [1:6809] "The Student of Prague" "The Student of Prague" "The Ghost Breaker" "The Hound of the Baskervilles" ...
$ startYear     : Date[1:6809], format: "1913-01-01" "1913-01-01" "1914-01-01" "1915-01-01" ...
$ runtimeMinutes: chr [1:6809] "85" "85" "60" "50" ...
$ decade        : num [1:6809] 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 ...
$ genre         : chr [1:6809] "Drama" "Fantasy" "Adventure" "Mystery" ...
$ rating        : num [1:6809] 6.5 6.5 5.2 3.1 3.1 6.6 6.6 5.8 6.8 6.8 ...
$ numVotes      : num [1:6809] 2063 2063 36 40 40 ...
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: To add data to your post I would recommend pasting the output of `dput(subgenres)` to your question. If your data frame is large then try `dput(head(subgenres, 20))`.

Comment: Your error message is unusual since in your posted code you are using `group_by`, `summarise` and `n` but the error message related to the `count` function. Are you sure your posted code is causing your posted error? If the glimpse of the data you provide is the same as `subgenres` I see nothing wrong with your posted code.

Comment: @LMc -- I added data for reproducibility. Thanks for your help! I'm not sure why the error is occurring. I just noticed another line before the error I pasted into the post: subgenres %>%
+   group_by(decade) %>%
+   summarise(count=n())
Error: 'format_error' is not an exported object from 'namespace:cli'

Comment: The `+` are your issue. Those are not part of the syntax you would use. Delete those and your code should run. Often `+` are used to add graphic layers in the `ggplot2` package. Here you have a data pipeline and you only need the pipe operator `%>%`.

Comment: Also, do not forget to pipe to `ungroup` after you are finished with group operations. Proceeding with grouped data often causes undesirable output. Alternatively, if you are using `dplyr` >= 1.1.0 then you can use the simply do `summarize(count = n(), .by = c(decade, genre))` for one time grouping operations.

Comment: The + aren't there in the actual code, unfortunately

Comment: With the sumarize(count...) suggestion -- I am using current dplyr -- I get the same error about format

Comment: Try restarting your R session. Only read in your data and run my posted code. That should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252631/discussion-between-tonya-howe-and-lmc).

Answer (score 1):

Using your posted data and code the following both work:

```
library(dplyr)

subgenres %>% 
  group_by(decade,genre) %>%
  summarise(count=n())

# dplyr >= 1.1.0
subgenres %>% 
  summarise(count=n(), .by = c(decade, genre))
```

When I insert the `+` into the code, I am able to somewhat replicate your error:

```
df %>% +
  group_by(decade,genre) %>% +
  summarise(count=n())

Error in group_by(decade, genre) : object 'decade' not found
```

**Output**

```
  decade genre     count
   <dbl> <chr>     <int>
1   1910 Drama         7
2   1910 Fantasy       2
3   1910 Adventure     1
4   1910 Mystery       2
5   1910 Crime         1
6   1910 Sci-Fi        3
7   1920 Thriller      2
8   1920 Mystery       2
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(tconst = c("tt0003419", "tt0003419", "tt0004013", 
"tt0005231", "tt0005231", "tt0005615", "tt0005615", "tt0005772", 
"tt0005951", "tt0005951", "tt0006434", "tt0006434", "tt0006554", 
"tt0006820", "tt0007111", "tt0008826", "tt0010323", "tt0010323", 
"tt0010323", "tt0010323"), primaryTitle = c("The Student of Prague", 
"The Student of Prague", "The Ghost Breaker", "The Hound of the Baskervilles", 
"The Hound of the Baskervilles", "Life Without Soul", "Life Without Soul", 
"Mortmain", "Satan's Rhapsody", "Satan's Rhapsody", "Black Orchids", 
"Black Orchids", "The Crimson Stain Mystery", "Homunculus, 1. Teil", 
"A Night of Horror", "Alraune", "The Cabinet of Dr. Caligari", 
"The Cabinet of Dr. Caligari", "The Cabinet of Dr. Caligari", 
"The Cabinet of Dr. Caligari"), startYear = structure(c(-20819, 
-20819, -20454, -20089, -20089, -20089, -20089, -20089, -19358, 
-19358, -19358, -19358, -19724, -19724, -19358, -18628, -18263, 
-18263, -18263, -18263), class = "Date"), runtimeMinutes = c("85", 
"85", "60", "50", "50", "70", "70", "\\N", "55", "55", "50", 
"50", "\\N", "69", "56", "80", "76", "76", "76", "76"), decade = c(1910, 
1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 
1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1920, 1920, 1920, 1920), genre = c("Drama", 
"Fantasy", "Adventure", "Mystery", "Crime", "Drama", "Sci-Fi", 
"Drama", "Fantasy", "Drama", "Drama", "Drama", "Mystery", "Sci-Fi", 
"Drama", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller", "Mystery", "Mystery", "Thriller"
), rating = c(6.5, 6.5, 5.2, 3.1, 3.1, 6.6, 6.6, 5.8, 6.8, 6.8, 
4.8, 4.8, 6.9, 6.1, 6.1, 5.5, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1), numVotes = c(2063, 
2063, 36, 40, 40, 53, 53, 23, 719, 719, 18, 18, 18, 91, 20, 51, 
62119, 62119, 62119, 62119)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```